# How to reset variable in image source?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, django

My problem is that I can't figure out how to reset a part of `<img src=''` which is a value from AJAX. Every time a javascript function is called this `ajax_value` is added so I ran in to a problem that it keeps adding this value without removieng it first. Looks like this:

Problem:

/static/lpr_images/2018_04_14_08_00.png2018_04_14_08_01.png

Situation:

```
<img src="{% static 'lpr_images/' %}" + ajax_value />
```

Things I tried but they didn't work:

`$("#lcp_img").reset();` raises error `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).reset is not a function`

Tried `.remove()` but that removes `img` tag.

*base.html*

```
...
<div class="modal-body">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <img id="lcp_img" src="{% static 'lpr_images/' %}" alt="My image"/>
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <br>
</div>
....

<script type="text/javascript">
function get_task_info(data) {
    $.ajax({
    ...
        document.getElementById('lcp_img').src += data.result.imageName;
        $("#exampleModal").modal('show');
};

function reset_img_src() {
        $('#lcp_img').reset();
      };
</script>
```

Comment: If you replace `src`, than it's gone forever. save it before replace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DOM doesn't have any concept of what was "originally" there; once you've changed it, the old value is gone. So you should save it somewhere else, and use that value each time. A good place to put things like this is in an attribute prefixed by `data-`, as jQuery can then use the [`.data()` method](http://api.jquery.com/data/#data-html5) to access it directly.

```
<img id="lcp_img" data-original-src="{% static 'lpr_images/' %}" alt="My image"/>
```

...

```
$.ajax({
...
    var img = $('#cp_img');
    img.attr('src', img.data('originalSrc') + data.result.imageName);
    $("#exampleModal").modal('show');
};
```

Comment: Thank You for information! This kinda works and in the same moment doesn't. Can't realy tell yet. Here is whats up now. First run ok, but if I close the modal and run that function again I get the same src. But if I wait a bit like 20 seconds and run it, it will show the corect/new src. I'm not sure which end couses this yet, but when I figure out I'll update here.

Comment: I figured out what was wrong. It was the fact that my `imageName` within a minute would not change its name, so I added seconds to name and everything works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this?

```
<div class="modal-body">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <img id="lcp_img" src="placeholder.jpg" data-base-path="{% static 'lpr_images/' %}" alt="My image"/>
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <br>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function get_task_info(data) {
    $.ajax({
    ...
        const $img = $('#lcp_img');
        $img.attr('src', $img.data('basePath') + data.result.imageName);
        $("#exampleModal").modal('show');
    });
  }
</script>
```

Edit: Daniel Roseman beat me to it. We had the similar idea. But like Daniel mentioned, you need a way to store or remember that original src or base path you want to use for the image location. That way, you can just append the data value to it.

Comment: I did try out Yore suggestion and it worked as well as Deniel Roseman's suggestion only upon first page load there was a error related to that `src`. Thenks never the less!